# Work with analytics with Google Drive's videos shared with colleagues

Tags: google-drive-api

I have the task to count how many users (colleagues) and (if it's possible), who have already viewed the videos that I have in a shared folder at my company's GSuite Google Drive.

Has anyone faced this before?

Any tips of advice will be very well received.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [User Report for Drive](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/user/drive) specifically designed for your purpose.

Also [Drive Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive).

Between those two I think you should find what you are looking for.